# Conditional Formatting, best way to highlight this?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

This column, I'm trying to figure out the best way to identify the following:

If F is 10, than H is green

If F is <10, but H is within 30 days Green, otherwise it's red.

```
=AND($F1<10, $H1-30<=TODAY())
```

This is what I have to make it red but the greens aren't working.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use rules based on the following formulas:

- Red: `=AND($F1<10,TODAY()-$H1>30)`
- Green: `=OR($F1=10,TODAY()-$H1<=30)`

[image]

**EDIT**:
If you want these rules to only apply in a specific workbook (that has a distinct name), you could potentially use formulas like the following, using `CELL` and `FIND`:

- Red: `=AND($F1<10,TODAY()-$H1>30,FIND("yourworkbookname",CELL("filename"))>0)`
- Green: `=AND(OR($F1=10,TODAY()-$H1<=30),FIND("yourworkbookname",CELL("filename"))>0)`

Change the `"yourworkbookname"` to your actual filename.

Comment: much appreciated! Works excellent! Do you know if INDIRECT works with conditional formatting? This sheet it applies too doesn't always stay in the workbook, and these rules would only apply to this sheet.

Comment: I'm not sure `INDIRECT` would be the solution there.

Comment: Any suggestions? That's the only thing I could think to apply to a specific sheet

Comment: When this sheet is moved to a new workbook, does its name change? What is the distinguishing characteristic between a sheet in this workbook vs. in another? The workbook name?

Comment: The worksheet name does not change, Sheet name "owssvr"

Comment: You could probably add a condition for the workbook name using `CELL("filename")` and `FIND`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222599/discussion-between-kevin-billings-and-bigben).